# Set option value with getElementsByName()

Tags: javascript

Having this fieldset:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>[*death]</legend>
    <select name=death  style="width: 120px">
        <option value=Dead>[*died]
        <option value=NotDead>[*alive]
        <option value="" selected>-
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

i want to set the `[2].value` to `"-"`.

i have tried without any success:

```
document.getElementsByName('death')[2].checked = 'true';
document.getElementsByName('death')[2].value = '-';
```

Same kind of code works fine for radio boxes, checked boxes or other inputs in the form. How to do it with the option select (which is not an input)?

Thanks

[EDIT] of course, appropriate fieldset is:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>[*death]</legend>
    <select name="death"  style="width: 120px">
      <option value="Dead">[*died]</option>
      <option value="NotDead">[*alive]</option>
      <option value="" selected>-</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

thanks.

Comment: Your `<option>` elements need closing tags as well: `</option>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a little bit unclear what you're asking. Are you simply asking to make the option at index 2 selected?

```
document.getElementsByName('death')[0].selectedIndex = 2;
```

Or, are you asking to change the value of option at index 2?

```
var d = document.getElementsByName('death')[0];
d.options[2].value = '-';
```

Comment: document.getElementsByName('death')[0].selectedIndex = 2; is fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to manipulate the `selected` property of your select object, try

`document.getElementsByName('death')[0].selectedIndex = 1;`

In english, this reads "set the selected option to the second option in the first element in the document with name 'death'".

Fixing your HTML might make the results of your javascript more predictable. Close your tags, quote your attribute values, as follows:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>[*death]</legend>
    <select name="death"  style="width: 120px">
      <option value="Dead">[*died]</option>
      <option value="NotDead">[*alive]</option>
      <option value="" selected>-</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fixing. Your suggestion is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using jQuery... it's easy...

```
j("#death").val(2)
```

Comment: using a javascript framework is definitely better. i'd like to point out, however, that his HTML is using a name and not an ID.

Comment: How if no ID (or, i could actually add an ID)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName('death')[2]` returns the third element named `death` - but you only have one element with that name. Instead, you want the first element named `death` (i.e. the one at index 0), and then you want its third option: `document.getElementsByName('death')[0].options[2].value = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alert example of how to access your specific option values with **getElementsByName**

```
alert(document.getElementsByName('death')[0].options[0].value); // will return Dead
alert(document.getElementsByName('death')[0].options[1].value); // will return NotDead
```