# How to set form option selected by value not by index

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, select, set

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343889/set-option-value-with-getelementsbyname/15136391#comment21306795_15136391) i have read how to set a form option selected by index

```
<select name="sel"> 
  <option value="o1">option1</option>
  <option value="o2">option2</option>
</select>

document.getElementsByName('sel')[0].selectedIndex = 0; or
document.getElementsByName('sel')[0].selectedIndex = 1;
```

but is it possible to set an option selected by referencing an option value instead of index?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just set the `value` property of the `<select>` element, as answered in [How do I programatically set the value of a select box element using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78932/851811)

```
<select name="sel"> 
    <option value="o1">option1</option>
    <option value="o2">option2</option>
</select>

<select name="sel"> 
    <option value="o1">option1</option>
    <option value="o2">option2</option>
</select>

document.getElementsByName("sel")[0].value="o2";
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7qkE/1/)

Comment: That's right. If you just `alert` or `console.log` the statement, you'll see it returns the value (`o2` in this case). Also, take into account the `selected` attribute is to be applied to the `<option>` elements, not the `<select>`. For instance, this would work: `document.getElementsByName("sel")[0].options[1].setAttribute("selected", "selected");`

Comment: ^^this is just the same as .selectedIndex=1; isn't it?

Comment: Indeed. You can set the selected option by index with the `selectedIndex` property or by value with the `value` property.

Comment: aahhhhh! ok! I get it! Thank you very very very very very much!

Comment: sorry, can't vote up your answer because i do not have enough reputation points...